# Database Channel ID Error

Tags: ee2, database

I've been working on a site for about a year now without issue.  There's a good number of channels and entries (about 11/2000+).  Within that last couple weeks, I seen something strange happen.  The channel ID's in the database seem to be in correct.

An example:

- Vendors channel_id = 4 in the exp_channels table
- in exp_channel_titles, channel_id 4 correlates to the title for the blog channel (channel 5).

Has anyone ever experienced this before?  I'm trying to go through and fix this, but it's now causing more issues (IE: when you go to a page with a safecracker form it's not pulling in the channel fields for that channel).

Have I completely screwed myself?  How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean the channel_id's are incorrect? Not sure how that is even possible unless someone altered the datatables or some custom add-on. What happens if you use a SQL client and update the channel_id's in the exp_channels table to what they should be? Are all the entries in the exp_channel_titles table match up 1-to-1 with the correct channel? I guess I would try to see if it's just a few entries or ALL of them is effected.

Comment: Hey Justin,  Yeah I tried this but now I'm getting more funky stuff going on.  Like I said, when I go to a safecracker form on the frontend, it show's the channel field short name, instead of the actual value.

Comment: I have never seem anything like that. Unless, as Justin Kimbrel says, something deliberately programmed did this, there must have been a serious glitch in the server. I suppose there are no older backups to look at? I can't see how EE can do this by itself without action at the DB level.

Comment: I was able to fix this by going through each channel in the CP and re-updating them to be pointing to the correct channel fields.  Not sure how this happened, but it's fixed now.  Thanks both Justin and John for the advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lucas fixed his issue and I quote:

> I was able to fix this by going through each channel in the CP and
>   re-updating them to be pointing to the correct channel fields.

Comment: Nice answer, you deserve +10 rep for that :)

Comment: Thanks! Wonder what's the best way to encourage Questioners to provide the answer after they have figured it out on their own and set it as the correct answer?

Comment: You could tell them in the comments they should post their solution. Or just jump in and take credit for it yourself :)

Comment: I would have, but I couldn't due to a 24 hour limit placed on the poster of the question answering.